# UTF8 Encoded messages broken charecter on php smpp sms sending

Tags: php, laravel, smpp

Hi am using php smpp sms sending package to work on socket sms sending.

```
$transport = new SocketTransport(array(config('app.smppHost')), config('app.smppPort'));
            $transport->setRecvTimeout(10000);
            $smpp = new SmppClient($transport);
```

I am sending with  `$encodedMessage = GsmEncoder::utf8_to_gsm0338($message);`

```
$smpp->sendSMS($from,$to,$encodedMessage,null,null);
```

**UPDATE**
But the sms is receiving with broken character.I am sending in  myn language and also tried as suggested

```
$smpp->sendSMS($from,$to,$encodedMessage,null,null);
```

But now half broken half proper message is sending. I think some encoded needed ???

Comment: are you sending different language message content other than English ?

Comment: yes i am sending sms in myanmar language

Comment: when sending sms what you need to pass  const DATA_CODING_DEFAULT = 8; to override in php smpp package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is special language encoded issue you need both override the encoded version in smpp package as well as encode the text itself.

First convert the string

```
mb_convert_encoding($message,'UCS-2',"utf8");
```

Then send sms in encoded in type 8. it should work properly

```
$smpp->sendSMS($from,$to,$encodedMessage,null,8);
```

Comment: Can you explain how it will work?

Comment: the first thing of encoding the string into ucs-2 which will encode in proper encode version for Burmese language and then after proper encoding it will also need to override the encoded text in sendSMS() function otherwise it will not work.